# Taylor series to solve limit equation

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I came across this problem while studying taylor series and limits.

$(1+1/n)^{(n+x)}=e$

calculate $x$ when $n$ tends toward infinity.

Looking at the question the obvious answer would be $0$, but through taylor series the answer becomes $x=1/2$. I can calculate it, but I have no intuition of why it is not $0$. Is my though of

$(1+1/n)^n = e \Rightarrow $

$(1+1/n)^{(n+x)}=e \Rightarrow $

$(1+1/n)^x=1$ wrong?

Thank you.

Edit:
I should probably call it Maclaurin expansion, and this is the solution I came to.

$y=\frac{1}n$,
${y\to0}$

$(1+y)^{\frac{1}y+x}=e$ $<=>$

$(\frac{1}y+x)ln(1+y)=1$ <=>

$x=\frac{y-ln(1+y)}{yln(1+y)}$

$ln(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}2+y^3B(y)$,  where B(y) is bounded close to $y=0$

$=> x=\frac{y-y+\frac{y^2}2-y^3B(y)}{y^2-\frac{y^3}2+y^4B(y)}=\frac{\frac{1}2-yB(y)}{1-\frac{y}2+y^2B(y)}\to\frac{1}2, y\to0$

This however is not my initial intuition. Therefore my assumption that x should be 0 is incorrect, but I don't know where my thinking is wrong.

Sorry for the clumsy math notation. It is a first time for me.

Comment: I don't know what you are using for the first "=>", it seems incorrect. You know that $(1+1/n)^n$ goes to $e$ so it may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+1/n)^{n+x}=(1+1/n)^n \cdot (1+1/n)^x  \to e \cdot1^x=e$$

as $n \to \infty$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial assumption to. But I don't know where the answer x=1/2 comes from if x can be any real number. Thank your for the respons.

Comment: But it can't be true for all x. If x tends to infinity then you have e*e=e, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+x}\implies \log(a_n)=(n+x)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$\log(a_n)=(n+x)\Bigg[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \Bigg]=1+\frac {2x-1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e+\frac {e(2x-1)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: I am with you until the last step where you multiply in e. Shouldn't the expression be the exponent to e base?

Comment: @ErikEriksson.The last step is correct. Check i the other way

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what I don't understand is why the term (2x-1) needs to be 0 which is the case when x=1/2. As long as n tends to infinity and x is bounded, doesn't everything except the first term (1), in the second to last step, tend to 0?

Comment: @ErikEriksson. The limit is $e$. The next term shows how the limit is approached.